# Managing user presence in real time database using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, user-presence

The below code update the presence field to true upon losing the internet or when I clear the app from memory. When I press the back or home button, the presence field in the database remains to true. How can I update presence field to false when the user press the home or back button.

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class Database {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  updatePresence() async {
    DatabaseReference ref =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(_auth.currentUser!.uid);

    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('.info/connected').onValue.listen((event) {
      if (event.snapshot.value == false) {
        return;
      }
      ref.onDisconnect().set({'presence': false}).then((value) {
        ref.set({'presence': true});
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pressing the `back` button does not close the connection to the database. Even if you exit the app, it may take a few minutes before the server detects that the client is gone and runs the `onDisconnect` handler(s) that you registered.

If you want to force the connection to be closed, you can call `goOffline()` as also explained in the documentation on [detecting connection state](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state):

> On Android, Firebase automatically manages connection state to reduce bandwidth and battery usage. When a client has no active listeners, no pending write or onDisconnect operations, and is not explicitly disconnected by the [`goOffline` method`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#goOffline()), Firebase closes the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.